# Time required to access the memory locations in the same cache line

Tags: memory, cpu-architecture, cpu-cache

Consider the big box in the following figure as a cache and the block as a single cache line inside the cache.

[image]

The CPU fetched the data (first 4 elements of the array **A**) from RAM into the cache block.

Now, my question is, does it takes exactly same time to perform read/write operations on all the 4 memory locations (`A[0]`, `A[1]`, `A[2]` and `A[3]`) in the cache block or is it approximately same?

**PS:** I am expecting an answer for ideal case where runtime to perform any read/write operation on any memory location is not affected by the operating system jitter on user processes or applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the line already hot in cache, time is constant for access to any aligned word in the cache.  The hardware that handles the offset-within-line part of an address doesn't have to iterate through to the right position or anything, it just MUXes those bytes to the output.

If the line was *not* already hot in cache, then it depends on the design of the cache.  If the CPU doesn't transfer around whole lines at once over a wide bus, then one / some words of the line will arrive before others.  A cache that supports **early-restart** can let the load complete as soon as the needed word arrives.

A critical-word-first bus and memory allow *that* word to be the first one transferred for a demand-miss.  Otherwise they arrive in some fixed order, and a cache miss on the last word of the line could take an extra few cycles.

Related:

- [Does cacheline size affect memory access latency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55647071/does-cacheline-size-affect-memory-access-latency)
- [if cache miss happens, the data will be moved to register directly or first moved to cache then to register?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47870086/if-cache-miss-happens-the-data-will-be-moved-to-register-directly-or-first-move)
- [which is optimal a bigger block cache size or a smaller one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46546454/which-is-optimal-a-bigger-block-cache-size-or-a-smaller-one)